# How to update datetime field to contain only the date or time part

Tags: sql, firebird

How can I update the field that contains the date/time information to contain just the date part of the data?  Something like the following:

```
update [EVENTS]
  SET [EVENT_DATE] = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [EVENT_DATE])
  WHERE EVENT_NUM = '8592'
```

I also need to get the equivalent to set it to just the time component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can truncate a `TIMESTAMP` to `DATE` or `TIME` by casting it:

```
cast(EVENT_DATE as DATE)
cast(EVENT_DATE as TIME)
```

This is also documented in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference [section on casts](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-casting), and in the Interbase 6 Embedded SQL Guide, section *Casting from SQL datatypes to datetime datatypes* on page 188. This manual is available from the Firebird website.

This only works in dialect 3. If you are still working with a dialect 1 database, you need to use the intermediate cast to `VARCHAR` (with a locale specific length of 10 or 11) as in [Maxims answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34823379/466862) to strip off the time portion. This is because `DATE` in dialect 1 is really a timestamp (and not only a date).

Answer (score 3):

You can use CAST() function:

```
update EVENTS
  set EVENT_DATE = cast(cast(EVENT_DATE as varchar(11)) as date)
  where EVENT_NUM = '8592'
```

Comment: You don't need to cast to varchar, cast the timestamp directly to date!

Comment: Probably it depends to used dialect and works in dialect 3. I use database with dialect 1 and there I have to cast to varchar at first because if I case to date it will not remove time.

Comment: That is because in dialect 1 (which BTW is deprecated since 2000), a `DATE` is a `TIMESTAMP`. Your trick works because using `VARCHAR(11)` will strip of the time info.